# Fail on debugging (or loading) the most basic VSIX project (Visual studio 2022 extension)

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2022, vsix

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio 2022 extension (A VSIX project).
The extension should be an AsyncPackage and wrap a code analysis class I wrote in order to
automatically apply it to all the projects.

I don't need buttons, menus nor anything visual to trigger the plugin.
Need to load it automatically as Visual studio 2022 starts (or after a solution starts)
and register it so it'll listen to the proper event.

I've created the project based on Microsoft's template - didn't work.
I update SDKTools as asked and symbols failed to load, and I can't debug anything.
Added some debug output in a static constructor - saw nothing in the output.

I installed an Extensibility Template Pack tool, trying it generated a project with their template.
It added the `[ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu", 1)]` (seems like referring my class like an attempt to add a menu item), then and only then I've managed to get the Symbols loaded, yet still no breakpoint worked whatsoever.

The parent class inherits from AsyncPackage.
Inheriting directly from AsyncPackage doesn't fix the problem.

[image]

The VSCT file (part of the template the new tool created)

[image]